# ReactJS Heroku Deployment Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, package

I have a ReactJS app that I am trying to deploy on heroku. It runs fine locally, but is not deploying correctly! On the page, I'm getting Cannot GET /

App link: https://nameless-spire-06291.herokuapp.com/

Console Errors:
1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2. Refused to load the image 'https://nameless-spire-06291.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

1. Here is my app structure in github
   https://github.com/sollama/reactJS-portfolio
2. Here is my server.js for reference:

   ```
   const express = require('express')
   const app = express()
   const path = require('path')
   const port = process.env.PORT || 3001

   app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

   app.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening on Port", port))
   ```
3. Package.json:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
       "build": "parcel build src/index.html",
       "start": "node server.js" ,
       "heroku-postbuild":"npm run build"
   },
   ```

Super new to all of this, so I'm not sure where to look  next and I would appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parcel's default output directory is `dist`, not `public`. That's the directory you want to pass to the `express.static` middleware so it looks for the resources in the correct directory.

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))
```

Comment: @SolanaLiu Great! I'm glad I could help! You can mark your question as resolved by clicking on the [checkbox to the left of an answer](https://i.imgur.com/Gz2ig3X.png).